# How do I make visual studio faster

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2012

I thought that Visual Studio 2012 would be fast after I installed my SSD disk but it still feels like I'm using a computer from the stone age when I'm building.

My computer is relatively fast (4 cores, 8 gb ram and ssd).

If I'm looking at the task manager neither of the cpu, memory or the disk seems to be working hard.

Is there anything to make VS faster. What is usually the bottle neck for VS?
If I'm building a new computer for VS, what should i prioritize?

Comment: How big is the project you're building and what kind of build times are we talking about?

Comment: Yes, Ive tried searching. The question here is more general than the hits Im getting. Im now really talking about a specific application or machine. I think most applications and machines are slow, even though they seem to not be working if I look in the task manager. I always need to wait for a minute or two...

Comment: Is it a clean install of windows?

Comment: Just to be clear: what is on the SSD? The Visual Studio installation and/or your project?

Comment: everything is on the SSD

Comment: Compilation is an integer problem, it isn't disk-bound.  Although anybody that spent the money on an SSD will *swear* it is makes a big difference.  The kind of fuzzy logic you get when you don't profile.

Comment: so if its an integer problem, what does that mean, that its the cpu witch makes VS run fast?